# Differentiate solution to Laplace's equation

Tags: integration, improper-integrals, harmonic-analysis, laplacian, greens-function

I am solving Laplace's equation
$$\nabla^2 \Phi = 0$$
in the half space of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with $\Phi = f(y,z)$ at $x=0$.

As is given here http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/reh10/lectures/nst-mmii-handout10.pdf, the solution is
$$\Phi(x,y,z) = \frac{x}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{f(y',z')}{(x^2 + (y-y')^2 + (z-z')^2)^{3/2}} \;  \textrm{d}y'\textrm{d}z'$$

However I want to calculate $\Phi_x|_{x=0}$, and I'm getting
$$\Phi_x = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{f(y',z') (-2x^2+(y-y')^2 + (z-z')^2)}{(x^2+(y-y')^2 + (z-z')^2)^{5/2}} \;  \textrm{d}y'\textrm{d}z'$$
and
$$\Phi_x|_{x=0} = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{\mathbb{R}^2} \frac{f(y',z')}{((y-y')^2 + (z-z')^2)^{3/2}} \;  \textrm{d}y'\textrm{d}z'$$
but this doesn't make sense even in a principal value way since the denominator doesnt change sign! What am I doing wrong?

Thanks :)

Comment: The appropriate space for the solution is the $H^1$ Sobolev space. You don't necessarily have derivatives like this, only (local) square integrability thereof.

Comment: @user66081 Ah yes agreed. So do you think the representation formula for $\Phi_x|_{x=0}$ is completely nonsensical?

Comment: It is the derivative across the domain boundary (=$yz$ plane) of the function $\Phi$ which is $H^1$ (although it is $C^\infty$ away from the boundary), so it is an $H^{-1/2}$ distribution in the $yz$ plane. That means it makes sense in the distributional/weak sense -- when you test it with a sufficiently smooth function of the $yz$ plane. I think...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have only differentiated the $x$ before the integral. You have also to add a contribution coming from the differentiation of $x$ *inside* the integral. I haven't performed the calculation, but may be you get some cancellation.

Comment: I have done the differentiation inside the integral, I will add another line to the question now to give my answer for $\Phi_x$